# Is there a way to create new Experience Fragments using AEM Content as a Service

Tags: aem

I am new to AEM's Content As A Service platform.

I have found many tutorials explaining how to develop Experience Fragments via the UI, and then set them up to be served via the Content As A Service layer.

However, I did not see any guides on creating fragments using the service.

---

My use case is essentially I have a bunch of structured content that I want to get into AEM (upwards of a 1000). All of it has the same structure, so it would be nice if I could just call the service to create Experience Fragments, instead of having to manually set them all up.

Comment: Did you see this: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/authoring/using/experience-fragments.html and this https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/structured-fragments-content-services-feature-video-use.html ?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen those - I am looking for documentation on how to create fragments programmatically.

Comment: Sure, take a look here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/content-fragments-delivery-considerations-article-understand.html and https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/xf/ExperienceFragmentsService.html#listPagesUsingVariation(com.adobe.cq.xf.ExperienceFragmentVariation...) There are code samples at the end.